# Can't find "setting -> iTunes & app store -> password settings" on iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios-appstore, password

I want to turn off password for free apps on my iPhone. But when I followed some tutorials found on the Internet, that is, setting -> iTunes & app store, there's no password settings option. Is there anything wrong?

I'm using iPhone 6+ with ios 12.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From article [Manage your iTunes Store and App Store password preferences](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204030#iOS):

> Touch ID or Face ID will always override whatever preference you set.

So first turn off Touch ID for iTunes by:

Settings -> Touch ID & Passcode -> Turnoff Touch ID for App Store.

Then go to Settings -> iTunes & App Store -> Password Settings.

Comment: Thank you. But does that mean I can't use touch ID for paid app anymore?

Comment: @D.H.Jong yes that seems very correct. I don't use any paid apps. It is a quick test If you could do it yourself and then tell me to edit the answer and close the question.

Comment: Your workaround works for me, and I think typing password for paid apps is not that bad, since I don't buy paid apps frequently.